# QProcess run ssh from living cmd session

Tags: c++, qt

```
QProcess m_prc_ssh;

m_prc_ssh.setProgram("cmd");
m_prc_ssh.start();
m_prc_ssh.write("chcp 1251\r\n");

connect(&m_prc_ssh, &QProcess::readyRead, this, &Tab_Server::on_ssh_output);
```

...

```
m_prc_ssh.write("c:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe\r\n");
```

...

```
void Tab_Server::on_ssh_output()
{
    m_edt_ssh_output->setText(m_edt_ssh_output->toPlainText() += "> " + QString::fromLocal8Bit(m_prc_ssh.readAll()) + "\r\n");
    m_edt_ssh_output->setText(m_edt_ssh_output->toPlainText() += "> " + QString::fromLocal8Bit(m_prc_ssh.readAllStandardOutput()) + "\r\n");
    m_edt_ssh_output->setText(m_edt_ssh_output->toPlainText() += "> " + QString::fromLocal8Bit(m_prc_ssh.readAllStandardError()) + "\r\n");
}
```

So here is problem.
cmd do not see c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe when file exists.
Everytime error 'The system cannot find the path specified.'
I can start calc.exe process or other processes (word, totalcmd or everything else) but not ssh... what is going on?

UPD: 
looks like qt process have no access to openssh folder when it runs under administrator priviligies
Also echo %PATH% output:

```
G:\Stereolife\SDK\Qt\5.9.0\static\\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0jal225p.zmb\lib\win32\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\golds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\golds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\golds\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
```

Comment: Is your program compiled as 32-bit, by chance? This might be caused by Windows [silently redirecting `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows\SysWoW64`](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/)

Comment: @Botje, yes silent redirection so silent, thank a lot